# How to fetch images and other details of nearby places using apple mapkit swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am using MKLocalSearchRequest() for searching nearby Places. In response i get only few parameters of the places searched like Name, placemark, phone number and url. I need more details like images, opening hours, rating, reviews, etc just like we get using google maps Api.

Any Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure out if this is possible? Is iOS capable of loading Places Results like in Apple Maps? If yes, is there any plan to open that API to developers at some point? If not, does anybody know if this is Apples Places database or if they are using third party information?